# PostgreSQL UPDATE statement with CASE and multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, case

I am trying to update a single column in a table based on 3 conditions.  I tried to use a CASE statement and I can get 2 of the conditions to work but not the 3rd.  Here's the criteria for the conditions:

1. If the field *transpond* = 0 then the field *transpondertype* should be 'N'
2. If the field *transpond* = 1 then the field *transpondertype* should be 'A'
3. If the field *modesquip* = 1 then the field *transpondertype* should be 'S'

And here's the SQL I came up with:

```
UPDATE "myDatabase".myTable
SET transpondertype=(CASE 
                       WHEN transpond=0 THEN 'N'      
                       WHEN transpond=1 THEN 'A'      
                       WHEN transpond=1 AND modesequip=1 THEN 'S'
                     END);
```

The *transpondertype* field gets updated properly with the first two conditions, it's the last WHEN statement that never updates correctly (it doesn't change the data at all).  I tried `WHEN modesequip=1 THEN 'S'` originally but that didn't work either.

How can I get the statement to update the *transpondertype* field for all 3 parts of the CASE statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE "myDatabase".myTable
SET transpondertype=(CASE 
                       WHEN transpond=0 THEN 'N'      
                       WHEN transpond=1 THEN
                                      CASE  WHEN modesequip=1 
                                      THEN 'S'
                                      ELSE 'A'
                                      END
                       
                          END);
```

Answer (score 0):

when transpond=1 and modesequip!=1 then 'A'